# JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase - Testing a process with DMN

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to test a process which contains a dmn table. When starting the process I am getting the issue DMN model 'EvaluatePreChecks' not found with namespace 'xxxxxxxxx.

A manual test and a e2e test works proprly.

My current code is that one:

DMN model 'EvaluatePreChecks' not found with namespace 'xxxxxxx'

```java
  public void testDMN() {
//      //KieSession workingMemory = createStatefulKnowledgeSessionFromRule(true);
//
    RuntimeManager runtimeManager = createRuntimeManager(Strategy.PROCESS_INSTANCE, "RunPreChecks",
        "RunPreChecks.bpmn");
    RuntimeEngine runtimeEngine = getRuntimeEngine(EmptyContext.get());
    KieSession ksession = runtimeEngine.getKieSession();
    MobileConcernFlowData mobileConcernFlowData = MobileConcernFlowData.builder()
        .concernId("concernId")
        .accountNumber(("accountNumber"))
        .hasActiveMobileSubscription(true)
        .hasDeliveredDevice(true)
        .build();

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("concernFlowData", mobileConcernFlowData);

     Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
     result.put("isValidMobileAccount", true);
     ProcessInstance processInstance = (ProcessInstance)ksession.startProcess('RunPreChecks", params);
     assertProcessInstanceActive(processInstance.getId(), ksession);

    runtimeManager.disposeRuntimeEngine(runtimeEngine);
     runtimeManager.close();
  }
```

Manual testing works properly.

Could please help anyone?

Thanks

To find examples, if it is or not possible what I am trying, etc.